# Using of Base Class and Derived Class and Inheritance

Tags: c#-4.0

I has a 2 Methods in Base Class(say Method1 and Method2) and having a two derived class (say Derived Class1 and Derived Class2) which are inheriting from Base Class

Now the Derived Class1 will get the two methods of Base Class(Method1 and Method2) **But Derived Class2 should get only one method of Base Class**(say Method1).

so, can any one suggest how can i proceed in this scenario(i am using C# as a Programming Language)

Thank in Advance!

Comment: that's not how inheritance is designed to work

Answer (score 0):

Declare the two method as **virtual** in the base class

```
virtual void Method1()
virtual void Method2()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement Method1 as an extension method and only have it referenced by DerivedClass1.